# Having Issues with Codeigniter App "The URI you submitted has disallowed characters."

Tags: php, codeigniter

I tried with almost all the methods posted in the thread.

My url is like : www.example.com/twilio_sms/update_status‏
Many posts explained to edit

```
if ( ! preg_match("|^[".str_replace(array('\\-', '\-'), '-', preg_quote($this->config->item('permitted_uri_chars'), '-'))."]+$|i", $str))
```

to

```
 if ( ! preg_match("|^[".($this->config->item('permitted_uri_chars'))."]+$|i", rawurlencode($str)))
```

but it leads to 404 error on that page.

/system/core/URI.php :

```
    <?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
/**
* CodeIgniter
*
* An open source application development framework for PHP 5.1.6 or newer
*
* @package      CodeIgniter
* @author       ExpressionEngine Dev Team
* @copyright    Copyright (c) 2008 - 2011, EllisLab, Inc.
* @license      http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/license.html
* @link     http://codeigniter.com
* @since        Version 1.0
* @filesource
*/

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
* URI Class
*
* Parses URIs and determines routing
*
* @package      CodeIgniter
* @subpackage   Libraries
* @category URI
* @author       ExpressionEngine Dev Team
* @link     http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html
*/
class CI_URI {

var $keyval         = array();
var $uri_string;
var $segments       = array();
var $rsegments      = array();

/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * Simply globalizes the $RTR object.  The front
 * loads the Router class early on so it's not available
 * normally as other classes are.
 *
 * @access  public
 */
function __construct()
{
    $this->config =& load_class('Config', 'core');
    log_message('debug', "URI Class Initialized");
}


// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Get the URI String
 *
 * @access  private
 * @return  string
 */
function _fetch_uri_string()
{
    if (strtoupper($this->config->item('uri_protocol')) == 'AUTO')
    {
        // If the URL has a question mark then it's simplest to just
        // build the URI string from the zero index of the $_GET array.
        // This avoids having to deal with $_SERVER variables, which
        // can be unreliable in some environments
        if (is_array($_GET) && count($_GET) == 1 && trim(key($_GET), '/') != '')
        {
            $this->uri_string = key($_GET);
            return;
        }

        // Is there a PATH_INFO variable?
        // Note: some servers seem to have trouble with getenv() so we'll test it two ways
        $path = (isset($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'])) ? $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] : @getenv('PATH_INFO');
        if (trim($path, '/') != '' && $path != "/".SELF)
        {
            $this->uri_string = $path;
            return;
        }

        // No PATH_INFO?... What about QUERY_STRING?
        $path =  (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) ? $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] : @getenv('QUERY_STRING');
        if (trim($path, '/') != '')
        {
            $this->uri_string = $path;
            return;
        }

        // No QUERY_STRING?... Maybe the ORIG_PATH_INFO variable exists?
        $path = str_replace($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], '', (isset($_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO'])) ? $_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO'] : @getenv('ORIG_PATH_INFO'));
        if (trim($path, '/') != '' && $path != "/".SELF)
        {
            // remove path and script information so we have good URI data
            $this->uri_string = $path;
            return;
        }

        // We've exhausted all our options...
        $this->uri_string = '';
    }
    else
    {
        $uri = strtoupper($this->config->item('uri_protocol'));

        if ($uri == 'REQUEST_URI')
        {
            $this->uri_string = $this->_parse_request_uri();
            return;
        }

        $this->uri_string = (isset($_SERVER[$uri])) ? $_SERVER[$uri] : @getenv($uri);
    }

    // If the URI contains only a slash we'll kill it
    if ($this->uri_string == '/')
    {
        $this->uri_string = '';
    }
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Parse the REQUEST_URI
 *
 * Due to the way REQUEST_URI works it usually contains path info
 * that makes it unusable as URI data.  We'll trim off the unnecessary
 * data, hopefully arriving at a valid URI that we can use.
 *
 * @access  private
 * @return  string
 */
function _parse_request_uri()
{
    if ( ! isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) OR $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '')
    {
        return '';
    }

    $request_uri = preg_replace("|/(.*)|", "\\1", str_replace("\\", "/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));

    if ($request_uri == '' OR $request_uri == SELF)
    {
        return '';
    }

    $fc_path = FCPATH.SELF;
    if (strpos($request_uri, '?') !== FALSE)
    {
        $fc_path .= '?';
    }

    $parsed_uri = explode("/", $request_uri);

    $i = 0;
    foreach(explode("/", $fc_path) as $segment)
    {
        if (isset($parsed_uri[$i]) && $segment == $parsed_uri[$i])
        {
            $i++;
        }
    }

    $parsed_uri = implode("/", array_slice($parsed_uri, $i));

    if ($parsed_uri != '')
    {
        $parsed_uri = '/'.$parsed_uri;
    }

    return $parsed_uri;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Filter segments for malicious characters
 *
 * @access  private
 * @param   string
 * @return  string
 */
function _filter_uri($str)
{
    if ($str != '' && $this->config->item('permitted_uri_chars') != '' && $this->config->item('enable_query_strings') == FALSE)
    {
        // preg_quote() in PHP 5.3 escapes -, so the str_replace() and addition of - to preg_quote() is to maintain backwards
        // compatibility as many are unaware of how characters in the permitted_uri_chars will be parsed as a regex pattern
        if ( ! preg_match("|^[".str_replace(array('\\-', '\-'), '-', preg_quote($this->config->item('permitted_uri_chars'), '-'))."]+$|i", $str))
        {
            show_error('The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.', 400);
        }
    }

    // Convert programatic characters to entities
    $bad    = array('$',        '(',        ')',        '%28',      '%29');
    $good   = array('&#36;',    '&#40;',    '&#41;',    '&#40;',    '&#41;');

    return str_replace($bad, $good, $str);
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Remove the suffix from the URL if needed
 *
 * @access  private
 * @return  void
 */
function _remove_url_suffix()
{
    if  ($this->config->item('url_suffix') != "")
    {
        $this->uri_string = preg_replace("|".preg_quote($this->config->item('url_suffix'))."$|", "", $this->uri_string);
    }
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Explode the URI Segments. The individual segments will
 * be stored in the $this->segments array.
 *
 * @access  private
 * @return  void
 */
function _explode_segments()
{
    foreach(explode("/", preg_replace("|/*(.+?)/*$|", "\\1", $this->uri_string)) as $val)
    {
        // Filter segments for security
        $val = trim($this->_filter_uri($val));

        if ($val != '')
        {
            $this->segments[] = $val;
        }
    }
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------
/**
 * Re-index Segments
 *
 * This function re-indexes the $this->segment array so that it
 * starts at 1 rather than 0.  Doing so makes it simpler to
 * use functions like $this->uri->segment(n) since there is
 * a 1:1 relationship between the segment array and the actual segments.
 *
 * @access  private
 * @return  void
 */
function _reindex_segments()
{
    array_unshift($this->segments, NULL);
    array_unshift($this->rsegments, NULL);
    unset($this->segments[0]);
    unset($this->rsegments[0]);
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Fetch a URI Segment
 *
 * This function returns the URI segment based on the number provided.
 *
 * @access  public
 * @param   integer
 * @param   bool
 * @return  string
 */
function segment($n, $no_result = FALSE)
{
    return ( ! isset($this->segments[$n])) ? $no_result : $this->segments[$n];
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Fetch a URI "routed" Segment
 *
 * This function returns the re-routed URI segment (assuming routing rules are used)
 * based on the number provided.  If there is no routing this function returns the
 * same result as $this->segment()
 *
 * @access  public
 * @param   integer
 * @param   bool
 * @return  string
 */
function rsegment($n, $no_result = FALSE)
{
    return ( ! isset($this->rsegments[$n])) ? $no_result : $this->rsegments[$n];
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Generate a key value pair from the URI string
 *
 * This function generates and associative array of URI data starting
 * at the supplied segment. For example, if this is your URI:
 *
 *  example.com/user/search/name/joe/location/UK/gender/male
 *
 * You can use this function to generate an array with this prototype:
 *
 * array (
 *          name => joe
 *          location => UK
 *          gender => male
 *       )
 *
 * @access  public
 * @param   integer the starting segment number
 * @param   array   an array of default values
 * @return  array
 */
function uri_to_assoc($n = 3, $default = array())
{
    return $this->_uri_to_assoc($n, $default, 'segment');
}
/**
 * Identical to above only it uses the re-routed segment array
 *
 */
function ruri_to_assoc($n = 3, $default = array())
{
    return $this->_uri_to_assoc($n, $default, 'rsegment');
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Generate a key value pair from the URI string or Re-routed URI string
 *
 * @access  private
 * @param   integer the starting segment number
 * @param   array   an array of default values
 * @param   string  which array we should use
 * @return  array
 */
function _uri_to_assoc($n = 3, $default = array(), $which = 'segment')
{
    if ($which == 'segment')
    {
        $total_segments = 'total_segments';
        $segment_array = 'segment_array';
    }
    else
    {
        $total_segments = 'total_rsegments';
        $segment_array = 'rsegment_array';
    }

    if ( ! is_numeric($n))
    {
        return $default;
    }

    if (isset($this->keyval[$n]))
    {
        return $this->keyval[$n];
    }

    if ($this->$total_segments() < $n)
    {
        if (count($default) == 0)
        {
            return array();
        }

        $retval = array();
        foreach ($default as $val)
        {
            $retval[$val] = FALSE;
        }
        return $retval;
    }

    $segments = array_slice($this->$segment_array(), ($n - 1));

    $i = 0;
    $lastval = '';
    $retval  = array();
    foreach ($segments as $seg)
    {
        if ($i % 2)
        {
            $retval[$lastval] = $seg;
        }
        else
        {
            $retval[$seg] = FALSE;
            $lastval = $seg;
        }

        $i++;
    }

    if (count($default) > 0)
    {
        foreach ($default as $val)
        {
            if ( ! array_key_exists($val, $retval))
            {
                $retval[$val] = FALSE;
            }
        }
    }

    // Cache the array for reuse
    $this->keyval[$n] = $retval;
    return $retval;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Generate a URI string from an associative array
 *
 *
 * @access  public
 * @param   array   an associative array of key/values
 * @return  array
 */
function assoc_to_uri($array)
{
    $temp = array();
    foreach ((array)$array as $key => $val)
    {
        $temp[] = $key;
        $temp[] = $val;
    }

    return implode('/', $temp);
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Fetch a URI Segment and add a trailing slash
 *
 * @access  public
 * @param   integer
 * @param   string
 * @return  string
 */
function slash_segment($n, $where = 'trailing')
{
    return $this->_slash_segment($n, $where, 'segment');
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Fetch a URI Segment and add a trailing slash
 *
 * @access  public
 * @param   integer
 * @param   string
 * @return  string
 */
function slash_rsegment($n, $where = 'trailing')
{
    return $this->_slash_segment($n, $where, 'rsegment');
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Fetch a URI Segment and add a trailing slash - helper function
 *
 * @access  private
 * @param   integer
 * @param   string
 * @param   string
 * @return  string
 */
function _slash_segment($n, $where = 'trailing', $which = 'segment')
{
    $leading    = '/';
    $trailing   = '/';

    if ($where == 'trailing')
    {
        $leading    = '';
    }
    elseif ($where == 'leading')
    {
        $trailing   = '';
    }

    return $leading.$this->$which($n).$trailing;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Segment Array
 *
 * @access  public
 * @return  array
 */
function segment_array()
{
    return $this->segments;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Routed Segment Array
 *
 * @access  public
 * @return  array
 */
function rsegment_array()
{
    return $this->rsegments;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Total number of segments
 *
 * @access  public
 * @return  integer
 */
function total_segments()
{
    return count($this->segments);
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Total number of routed segments
 *
 * @access  public
 * @return  integer
 */
function total_rsegments()
{
    return count($this->rsegments);
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Fetch the entire URI string
 *
 * @access  public
 * @return  string
 */
function uri_string()
{
    return $this->uri_string;
}


// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Fetch the entire Re-routed URI string
 *
 * @access  public
 * @return  string
 */
function ruri_string()
{
    return '/'.implode('/', $this->rsegment_array()).'/';
}

    }
   // END URI Class

   /* End of file URI.php */
   /* Location: ./system/core/URI.php */
```

/application/config/config.php

```
   $config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-?';
   $config['allow_get_array'] = TRUE;
   $config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
   $config['controller_trigger'] = 'c';
   $config['function_trigger'] = 'm';
   $config['directory_trigger'] = 'd'; // experimental not currently in use
```

When i copied the url from browser it is like :

```
https://example.com/twilio_sms/update_status%E2%80%8F
```

And it should be like :

```
https://example.com/twilio_sms/update_status
```

Why it is adding extra characters ?

Comment: What is creating that url? A link inside your site? Something is passing illegal characters to the end of the URL. %E2%80%8F translates to â` which are obviously disallowed characters

Answer (score 1):

Don't mess with the core files..
You can write your own function to clean URL's
Read this article  http://www.florian-hacquebart.eu/?p=161

Comment: This is totally different thing. I dont want to replace _ to -

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this helps you... but i made a little modification to check the actual disallowed character that is showing the error,  in the core file..

```
 path >  system>core>Input.php   // arounrd line 561

 function _clean_input_keys($str)
 {
    if ( ! preg_match("/^[a-z0-9:_\/-]+$/i", $str))
    {
    exit('Disallowed Key Characters.'.$str); //added str to print the $str that was causing the problem
     }
 .....
```

you can do this to check if it is the underscore(_).. or someother charecters that is causing the error... and likewise you can change in your config file..

hope this helps

Comment: how to print $str, i added this in a function   
function update_status($str)
{echo $str; 
but i am still getting same issue, and its not even printing the value.